# I am on the sickness layoff

Tags: phrase-usage

I'd like to ask how a native speaker expresses the fact that someone is not able to fulfill the obligations due to illness.

*Sorry, I cannot take part in the conference. I am on the sickness layoff.*

Is the second sentence OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "sickness layoff" is not a common expression.

If you are absent from work due to illness you are "on sick leave". However in your particular case you can just say

> I cannot attend the conference due to illness.

If you are "laid off" this means you lose your job, because the company can no longer pay you. It happens if the company goes bust, gets smaller or no longer needs someone to do your job.  It happens when you lose your job, but not because you have done something wrong.

> John was laid off when the factory replaced him with robots.

Answer (score 1):

The more common expression is [**sick leave**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sick%20leave), which has two senses:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1** : an absence from work permitted because of illness
>   **2** : the number of days per year for which an employer agrees to pay employees who are sick.

So, in your sentence (with some minor edits), you would say:

> Sorry, I can't take part in the conference. I am on *sick leave*.

Or:

> I'm not feeling well. I'm going to have to take *sick leave*.

Of course, if you're not referring to absence from work, you could just say:

> I can't attend. I'm feeling (sick / ill / under the weather).

---

Merriam-Webster also gives examples of the other sense:

> // employee benefits such as vacation time and *sick leave*
>   // We are allotted three weeks annual *sick leave*.

Comment: layoff is wrong. Period. I upvoted.